# convert enum members to string

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

I am trying to play around enums in solidity, during which I came across following questions--

> 1. Is it possible convert enum members to string??

I am trying to get enum members and convert them to string, It always returns integer ie. position of member, 
following is the code snippet

```
contract c{
    enum Numbers {zero,one,two,three,four}

    Numbers number;

    function getFirstNumber(){
         number=Numbers.zero; //works fine
         uint num=uint(Numbers.zero);//works fine
         string stringNum=string(Numbers.zero);// throws error
    }
}
```

is it possible to convert them to strings, by using any other approach.

> 2. Is it possible to get enum members by using index??

Can we get enum member by using the index / position of the member in enum
following is the code snippet I am trying.

```
contract c{
    enum Numbers {zero,one,two,three,four}

    Numbers number;
    function getByIndex(int position){
         number=Numbers.zero; //works fine

         //tried somthings like
         number=Numbers[0];//throws error
         number=Numbers.get(position);// throws error
    }
}
```

Is this possible to get them using position

> 3. Is it possible to check existence of members using string??

I need to check that the provided string exist in the enum, following is the code snippet I am trying

```
contract c{
    enum Numbers {zero,one,two,three,four}

    Numbers number;
    function checkIfExist(string member) returns(bool exists){

         //tried somthings like

         for(uint i=0;i<Number.length;i++){
            if(string(Number[i]==member){ //throws error
                return true;
            }
            else{
                exists=false;
            }
         }

         //also tried
         uint flag=Number.member;//throws error
         if(flag>0){
              return true;
         }
    }
}
```

is it possible to do this by any approach

Answer (score 2):

The compiled code doesn't know anything about the names of the enum elements. You can prove this by arbitrarily changing their names and compiling with `solc --bin`, and you'll see that they make no difference to the compiled code. So no, you can't get them by calling the contract.

You could of course add a separate mapping to the contract hard-coding that if asked for `"two"` it should return `Numbers.two` and vice versa, but you'd have to pay gas to carry this extra data when you deployed the contract.

The simplest thing is usually just to maintain a copy of the enum mapping wherever you need to call it, eg if you access the contract from a JavaScript DApp, keep a copy of the enum mappings in your JavaScript.